# Custom Lookup on Activity Not Found in Apex

Tags: apex, limits, activities, feature-activation

I have the beta version of the ability to create custom lookup fields on activities enabled. So when I create a look up field to Account I would expect to see 3 relationships to account: AccountID, WhatId, and the newly created lookup field we'll call it Account__c. When I execute this code snippet in execute anonymous it doesn't display the custom lookup field:

```
Schema.DescribeSObjectResult describe = Account.sObjectType.getDescribe();
for (Schema.ChildRelationship relationship : describe.getChildRelationships())
{
    system.debug(relationship);
}
```

It lists all the relationships except the custom one that was created on task. Is this a known issue?

Comment: That certainly sounds like a platform bug, have you opened a case with support yet?

Comment: BTW, I don't see anything like this listed in the [Summer 15 Known Issues](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_index?tag=Summer%2015)

Comment: woah where do you sign up for this beta version? from here https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=08730000000BrPdAAK I see that task lookup has highest threshold but how did you manage to get an org, is this one of the blackbox features provided to specific customers?